# sonar for .net 4 in ccnet

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, sonarqube, ccnet-config

hi all
does sonar support .net 4?
if so how can i integrate sonar with cruisecontrol.net (ccnet) with out using maven o anything else.just sonar and ccnet..
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the wiki page mentioned before and if you encounter any trouble, feel free to register to the user mailing list and ask for help (see http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/).
For now, even if sonar 2.6 may use ant or a simple command line to trigger the analysis on a java project, maven is mandatory for a .net project. This will change pretty soon. I am working with the guys from sonarsource to give birth to a new "C# plugin"... First version probably at the beginning of this summer.
For now, only solution I see to integrate sonar with ccnet is to launch a maven command line from ccnet.

Answer (score 1):

I documented my experience setting up Sonar with my C# projects.  I used TeamCity instead of CCNet, but that's a small portion of the overall setup, so should be straightforward to configure.  http://www.wrightfully.com/setting-up-sonar-analysis-for-c-projects/